# COUNTIF and formulas on first instance of a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a long, relatively simple, list of people's names and data, with some repeating occurrences, like so:

> ```
>    A          B        C
> John Doe - 2020201 - Red: 25
> John Doe - 2020201 - Blue: 23
> John Doe - 2020201 - Green: 2
> John Doofus - 250342 - Red 25
> Jane Doe - 41412 - Red: 21
> Jane Doe - 41412 - Blue: 6
> ```

Let's say column B is a social security number or something along those lines so it's unique for each person.

To this, I added a simple COUNTIF(B:B) column all along the left side of the table to show how many rows there are for the same person, like so:

> ```
> 3 John Doe - 2020201 - Red: 25
> 3 John Doe - 2020201 - Blue: 23
> 3 John Doe - 2020201 - Green: 2
> 1 John Doofus - 250342 - Red 25
> 2 Jane Doe - 41412 - Red: 21
> 2 Jane Doe - 41412 - Blue: 6
> ```

I would like to know:

1. How to make it so the COUNTIF "counter" stays on the first instance of each name, without having to manually paste/delete the formula in the appropriate rows to make it look like so:

> ```
> 3 John Doe - 2020201 - Red: 25
>   John Doe - 2020201 - Blue: 23
>   John Doe - 2020201 - Green: 2
> 1 John Doofus - 250342 - Red 25
> 2 Jane Doe - 41412 - Red: 21
>   Jane Doe - 41412 - Blue: 6
> ```

2. Similarly, I would also like to know if there's any way of autofilling a formula in a column but make it so that it just applies to the first occurrence of a value in another column, like so:

> ```
> John Doe - 2020201 - Red: 25  - FORMULA runs because first instance of 2020201
> John Doe - 2020201 - Blue: 23 - FORMULA doesn't run
> John Doe - 2020201 - Green: 2 - FORMULA doesn't run
> John Doofus - 250342 - Red 25 - FORMULA runs because first instance of 250342
> Jane Doe - 41412 - Red: 21 - FORMULA runs because first instance of 41412
> Jane Doe - 41412 - Blue: 6 - FORMULA doesn't run
> ```

Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could be used, where the formula will run unless B2 = B1.

```
=if(B2=B1,'',countif_formula).
```

Comment: That seems to work quite well to answer #1. Thank you!

Comment: Would it also work for your second question? Perhaps I don't fully understand the 2nd one, but I interpret the same as the first as it's currently written.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It does work. I still would like to see if there are other alternatives because I already had a very long and clumsy formula set up with a 'run if condition is true' setup instead of having the value_if_true be " " and I tried swapping things around but I ended up breaking stuff.